# How to check correct digit positioning?

Tags: python

I made a program that generates a random number between 100 and 999. The user needs to input an integer to guess the random number. The game will only end if the user inputs 0 or has 5 incorrect tries.
How would I modify it such that when the user inputs the answer, the program will tell you whether the integer entered is at the correct position or the correct digit at the wrong position? Like in this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtUt0.jpg

```
import random
num = random.randint(100,999)
attempts = 1
while attempts < 6:
    guess = int(input("Try #{} - Please enter your guess: ".format(attempts)))
    if guess == num:
        print("Great! You have gotten the correct number!")
    else:
        print("Your guess is incorrect")
        attempts = attempts + 1
else:
    print("The correct number is {}, The game has ended.".format(num))
```

Comment: compare strings, not numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will tell the users which position are correct in case the number and the guess are different.

```
import random
num = random.randint(100,999)
attempts = 1
print(num)
while attempts < 6:
    guess = int(input("Try #{} - Please enter your guess: ".format(attempts)))
    if guess == num:
        print("Great! You have gotten the correct number!")
        break
    else:
        guess_str = str(guess)
        for i, val in enumerate(str(num)):
            if guess_str[i] == val:
                print("The position num {} is correct".format(i + 1))
        print("Your guess is incorrect")
        attempts = attempts + 1
else:
    print("The correct number is {}, The game has ended.".format(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing this. You may convert your input to a string using `str(my_num)` and check if `str(digit) in str(my_num)` and to check if it is in the correct position use `str(digit) == str(my_num)[correct_position]`

The second way is using divisions and modulu. using `(my num // (10 ** position)) % 10` will give you the digit in the position so you could easily compare.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your else statement as :

```
num = str(num)
guess = str(guess) 
correct_digit = 0
correct_digit_position = 0
for i in guess:
   if i in num:
       correct_digit += 1
       if num.index('i') == guess.index('i') :
           correct_position += 1
           correct_digit -= 1
print(f"Try #{attempts} - {correct_position} correct digit and position, {correct_digit} correct digit but wrong position ")
```